# Chart control not working in rdlc file in ASP.NET Core 3.1 web forms

Tags: c#, rdlc, .net-core-3.1

I am using `.rdlc` files to generate reports in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I am encountering an error when using a line chart in the `.rdlc` file.

Instead of the chart, the PDF displays an error message

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. The system cannot find the file specified'

The data is successfully loading in the grid and able to download the file, but the issue is specific to the chart control in the `.rdlc` file. Please see this screenshot

[image]